# make a condition to the IE browser?

Tags: javascript

```
 <script language = "javascript">
  if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
begin = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") +
"MSIE ".length;
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf(";", begin) > 0) {
end = navigator.userAgent.indexOf(";", begin);
} else {
end = navigator.userAgent.indexOf(")", begin)
+ 2;
}
document.getElementById("targetDiv").innerHTML =
"You are using Internet Explorer " +
navigator.userAgent.substring(begin, end);
}
}
    </script>
```

why when make a condition to the IE browser,there added an `else` part? what's the meaning and effect of it? thank you,

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use Javascript to sniff out Internet Explorer.  [Welcome to HTML conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html):

**FOR DETECTING IE:**

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <!-- Add IE script file here -->
<![endif]-->
```

**FOR DETECTING ANYTHING EXCEPT IE:**

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
    <!-- Add non-IE script file here -->
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Javascript isn't a good solution for browser sniffing because you should only use it as a way to "progressively enhance" a website.  If your website is going to break when someone doesn't have Javascript enabled, then that's not acceptable.  Build your website and use Javascript to add the effects necessary to create a better experience.

This is especially true if you already have a native way of detecting for Internet Explorer.  Why not use a method which will work in all browsers as opposed to a method that will work in browsers that only allow Javascript?  You can never be so sure.

Comment: Your 'not IE` checking is broken.

Comment: Whoops, fixed.  Thanks Jeremy!